# How to programmatically refresh a Sitecore screen?

Tags: experience-editor, events

I have an Event firing on item:saved, that ends up modifying some fields on **the same** item being saved. This of course is not immediately reflected on the Sitecore interface, causing a misleading message if the Content Editor performs further changes and then saving again. In the worst case scenario, a second save would overwrite the effects of the event.

Is there a way to force the values of the item currently being viewed to refresh following my changes?

Comment: Looking for something similar to this.? https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/load-or-reload-an-item-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

Comment: do it in `item:saving` instead

Comment: I'll just add what I always add whenever talking about `item:saved` or `item:saving` event handlers: make sure you include a conditional check to ensure you don't accidentally re-process the same item multiple times (or the wrong type of items).